# Spatial relation (correlation) between polylines

Tags: software-recommendations, spatial-analysis, geology

I'm evaluating the spatial relationship between two polylines (morpholineament and magnetic lineament). If this two polylines are spatially correlated or not.
Traditionally, this analysis is realized by visual inspection:

> The polyline A is close to polyline B, so they are spatially correlated

[image]

This is a subset of my polylines. In a visual inspection, the E-W and NE-SW sets are spatially correlated to the magnetic lineaments. However, this structures may shift, be dislocated or rotated, so this traditional method may not work properly.

Carranza (2009), for instance, uses the cumulative frequence of the distance between the mineral deposits (point) and fault system (polyline) to analyze the spatial correlation.

> Carranza, E.J.M., 2009, Controls on mineral deposit occurrence
> inferred from analysis of their spatial pattern and spatial
> association with geological features: Ore Geology Reviews, v. 35, p.
> 383–400, doi:10.1016/j.oregeorev.2009.01.001.

I can "convert" one of my polyline to points and apply the Carranza's method, however I don't think this will be correct.

So, I would like to avoid the visual inspection and apply some statistic method, do you know any method to do so?

Comment: You don't make clear what question you are asking or how you have progressed so far.

Comment: @LeighBettenay I've just updated the question. Thanks for your advice.